# API call to github while knitting error 'needs an interactive environment'

Tags: r, github, knitr, httr

My API call to github in the R-Studio console works just fine (httr package) but breaks whenever I attempt to knit a pdf. In the console I have to manually go to 'localhost:1410' when first authorizing my credentials but apparently this is unable to happen while knitting.

````
```{r}
oauth_endpoints("github")
myapp <- oauth_app("github", "xxxxxxxxxx")
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp)
gtoken <- config(token = github_token)
req <- with_config(gtoken, GET("https://api.github.com/repos/mbostock/d3/stats/participation"))
stop_for_status(req)
result = content(req)
```
````

The error produced is

```
Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment. Execution halted.
```

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not caching your credentials with the local cache?

Comment: Heh, the reason is that I had no idea what a 'local cache' was. I used  `library(SOAR)` with `Store` function and everything is working. Maybe if I paid attention at Rice I would have known. Say hi to Dr. Ensor. Thanks!

Comment: @TedPetrou Create the token in an interactive session and set `cache=TRUE`. Then you can load the cached token in your knitr doc.